# How to get the string return value in the super call in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I am extending a Java class using proxy in Clojure. I want to get the string value returned when I call the super call. How to do that?

```
public class Baseclass {
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello from Baseclass";
    }
}
```

Clojure code:

```
(ns subclass.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:import Baseclass))

(defn my-greet [] 
    (proxy [Baseclass] []
        (greet []
            (proxy-super greet)))

(defn -main [& args]
    (my-greet))
```

This return `#object[subclass.core.proxy$Baseclass$ff19274a 0x2dd8954f "subclass.core.proxy$Baseclass$ff19274a@2dd8954f"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proxy` creates an instance of a class but doesn't call any methods on it. If you want to call `greet`, then call `greet`.